# What's the difference between Type.IsSubclassOf and TypeInfo.IsSubclassOf?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I just noticed there are two methods to check if a class is derived from another class:

- The 'old' method which exists since .NET framework 1.1 : [`Type.IsSubclassOf(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof(v=vs.110).aspx)
- A 'new' method which exists only since .NET framework 4.5 : [`TypeInfo.IsSubclassOf(Type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651403(v=vs.110).aspx)

Is there any reason this newer method was created? From what I see they both do the same.

Comment: "Is there any reason..." is hopefully answered by the blog post [Evolving the Reflection API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api/) - "`System.Type` is the primary abstraction and entry point into the reflection model. It is used to describe two related but different concepts, *reference* and *definition*, and enables operations across both. This lack of separation of concepts is the primary motivation for changing the reflection API."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It makes much more sense now, great article!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TypeInfo.IsSubclassOf` is inherited from `Type.IsSubclassOf`. This is the same method. There is no "new" method in `TypeInfo` - [`TypeInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) itself is the *new* class in .NET metadata model.

Comment: You're right, a bit unclear in the documentation in my opinion, thanks!